# WrongTypeOfReturnValue mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a method inside a class that I am mocking that returns a boolean value.

```
@Service
    public boolean writeToHDFS(HashMap<String, String> tableHistoryMap, String text, String tableName, String siteName, String customer,
          boolean incremental){
        try{
          String absoluteFilepath = hdfsService.generateHDFSAbsolutePathNoDate(tableHistoryMap, tableName, siteName, customer, incremental);
          Path writeFile = new Path(absoluteFilepath);

      if (!hdfsService.HDFSFileExists(writeFile)) {
        writer = hdfs.create(writeFile, false);
        logger.info("hdfs file create set up");
      }
      else {
        writer = hdfs.append(writeFile);
        logger.info("hdfs file append set up");
        //TODO: WRITING HERE
        //IF stripping capability is enabled, strip headers then
        text = hdfsService.parseText(stripHeaders, text, tableName);
      }
      if(hdfsService.writerHDFS(writer,text)){
        return true;
      }

    }
    catch(Exception ex){
      logger.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
  }



@MockBean
WriteDataIntoHDFSService writeDataIntoHDFSService
@Test
  public void testDepositData(){
    KafkaMessage kafkaMessage = new KafkaMessage();
    kafkaMessage.setInitialLoadRunning(true);
    kafkaMessage.setCustomer("customer");
    kafkaMessage.setMessageContent("message");
    kafkaMessage.setTableName("table");
    kafkaMessage.setInitialLoadComplete(false);
    HashMap<String, String> tableMap = new HashMap<>();
    tableMap.put("Test","Test");

    when(writeDataIntoHDFSService.writeToHDFS(tableMap, kafkaMessage.getMessageContent(), kafkaMessage.getTableName(), "Site", kafkaMessage.getCustomer(),
       false)).thenReturn(true);

    Assert.assertTrue(kafkaService.depositData(kafkaMessage,"test",kafkaMessage.getCustomer(),tableMap));
  }
```

The assertion fails and I debugged it and it returns WrongTypOfReturnValue at when()...thenReturn(true). It says boolean cannot be returned by toString().

Log:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Boolean cannot be returned by toString()
toString() should return String
***
If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.
```

dataDeposit:

```
public boolean depositData(KafkaMessage kafkaMessage, String topic, HashMap<String, String> tableHistoryMap){
   String customer = getCustomer(topic);
    String site = getSite(topic);
    if (kafkaMessage.isInitialLoadRunning() && !kafkaMessage.isInitialLoadComplete()) {
      //runInitial(kafkaMessage, splitKafkaTopic[2]);
      if (writeDataIntoHDFSService
          .writeToHDFS(tableHistoryMap, kafkaMessage.getMessageContent(), kafkaMessage.getTableName(), site,
              kafkaMessage.getCustomer(), false)) {
        logger.info("Wrote initial data into HDFS file for: " + kafkaMessage.getTableName());

        synchronized (lock) {
          kafkaConsumer.commitSync();
          logger.info("Kafka commit sync done for initial load.");
        }
         return true;
      }
    }
return false;
```

}

UPDATE: not even sure what I did but it seems to be working now...

Comment: Because `depositData` method returns `String` rather than `boolean`.

Comment: Can you printout your exception from the log ?

Comment: huh? I didn't even show the depositData method. That method is returning a boolean as well

Comment: can you post the depositData method

Comment: Debug depositData and make sure it's not throwing any exception, because i see you're not catching any exception inside it.

Comment: I debugged it and at this point:  if (writeDataIntoHDFSService
          .writeToHDFS(tableHistoryMap, kafkaMessage.getMessageContent(), kafkaMessage.getTableName(), site,
              kafkaMessage.getCustomer(), false)), this equals false. Meaning, when()...thenReturn(true) didn't work correctly.

Comment: Are you sure about the tableMap ? try to use the same instance used inside When(..), probably mockito got confused and treats it as different instance even with same values.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Sorry i thought you're using a different instance of tableMap, my idea is that when(..) fails in case the instances of the arguments passed to _writeToHDFS()_ differ between assertion and real call. Double check you're passing same instance not only same value .. I'll look into it deeper and try to figure out what's wrong , but meanwhile just debug and double check the values of arguments passed to _writeToHDFS()_ inside _depositData()_

Comment: For some reason, it seems to work when I change the return type from boolean to String...